# Print with lpr to userid protected network printer

Tags: command-line, security, cups

How can I print from the command line (e.g., with << lpr >>) to a network printer that requires a user id?

When I use the printer from an application, a dialog box requests my user id and a password.  There is no password, I give it my user id and it prints.

I've tried using the -U option to lpr, but this doesn't work.

Doing this from a Macbook.

Comment: If `-U` doesn't work, then there is a bug in CUPS.  Consider [filing a bug report](http://www.cups.org/str.php?U).

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe.  CUPS is pretty widespread, and this is a pretty simple functionality.  I find it a lot easier to imagine the problem is operator error / ignorance, rather than a CUPS bug.  I'll do this if I can't find anything after some more looking around.